# Why request fails to download an excel file from web?

Tags: python, excel, file, url, request

the url link is the direct link to a web file (xlsb file) which I am trying to downlead. The code below works with no error and the file seems created in the path but once I try to open it, corrupt file message pops up on excel. The response status is 400 so it is a bad request. Any advice on this?

```
url = 'http://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/static-files/55ff50da-ac65-410d-924c-fe45b23db298'
file_name = r'local path with xlsb extension'


with open(file_name, "wb") as file:
    response = requests.request(method="GET", url=url)
    file.write(response.content)
```

Comment: I am struggling to copy paste the part of code I want into the code editor. I have been editing perhaps 5 times now. Copy pasting code has glitches.

Comment: Just a note for future edits, you don't need to indent any lines and can also wrap the lines with``` code fences. For example ```python3 at the start to indicate the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems working for me. Try this out:

```py
from requests import get

url = 'http://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/static-files/55ff50da-ac65-410d-924c-fe45b23db298'

# make HTTP request to fetch data
r = get(url)

# check if request is success
r.raise_for_status()

# write out byte content to file
with open('out.xlsb', 'wb') as out_file:
    out_file.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Can you open the xlsb file and see the content? Now with your code this message appears in output:  out.xlsb is not UTF-8 encode

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Yep I am able to open it fine and view the content with MS Excel.

Comment: which Python version are you using? not sure if it matters, but I'm using 3.9.

Comment: I had an error in my path. Now works perfectly with your code. Thanks! I need to dig in to understand why the initial code I posted was giving me error.

Comment: no problem, glad to know that it helped!